# There's a way to redirect CURL output to Firefox?

Tags: firefox, curl

I have a bunch of requests in my application that return html.
So, there's a way to redirect the CURL output to my browser so it renders its content? Something like the code below (which does not work).

```
curl $MY_URL | firefox
```

Do you know any way of accomplish that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following command worked for me using Cygwin (running under Win7) and Ubuntu 14.04.2:

```
curl http://www.rosstronics.biz | firefox "data:text/html;base64,$(base64 -w 0 <&0)"
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends a bit on how you open Firefox and whether or not it's acceptable to leave behind a copy of the HTML of the article.

Here's one way to achieve this on a Mac using Bash shell that leaves behind an extra file in /tmp/. Whether that's a feature or a big or an unimportant detail is up to you.

```
curl https://www.example.com > /tmp/foo.html && open -a firefox /tmp/foo.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that an easy way to do it is to put the output into an html file, and double click the file to open it in a browser. Every time you run the request, just refresh the browser and it will display the new changes.

so `"curl [data and options] > response.html"` then double click the html

Answer (score 0):

Pipe it to node, write a script to read stdin and pipe it out.

Comment: Maybe a less toilsome way? If there's no other, ill definetively try that.